# How to call a Public Shared Sub with parameters

Tags: .net, vb.net, events

I've a ***form_click*** event and also a ***Public Shared Sub*** under a single class.
Now I need to call this ***Shared Sub*** from other events. But I'm facing issues on passing the parameters to the calling Sub.

Could you please help me here, and also explain whats going down here!

```
Public Class SC
' More codes here.......

    Public Sub SC_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
        Try

            Dim document As New Document()
            Dim section As Section = document.AddSection()

            'SaveDoc(document)  I WANT TO CALL THIS INSIDE Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub SaveDoc(document As Document)
        Dim fname = InputBox("Enter file name:", "file name")
        document.SaveToFile(fname & ".docx", FileFormat.Docx)
        MsgBox("""" & fname & ".DOCX"" is saved!")
    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click
        'I Want To Call SaveDoc() Here with Params
    End Sub
```

I've tried changing the Sub to a shared Function, but the problem exists.
Please help me pass the params!

By now, you already understood this is a tool to take screenshot for my own.
Currently, the word file is getting saved on every click!

When I call the shared Sub saveDoc() from within the Form_Click event, this works perfectly fine. But I need to break the code into separate Event since I want to save the file only once, not on every Click.

Source Code:

[Click HERE to view the source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/)

IDE Suggestion:

[Click HERE to view the IDE Suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/)

Comment: You call a Shared Sub like any other sub. But you have the variable fname which isn't initialized anywhere. Seems like it should be a parameter.

Comment: `fname` is probaly an instance member (a Field) in the main class. You cannot use an instance member in a static (Shared) method. Remove the shared modifier or add a `fileName as String` parameter and pass that member as the argument.

Comment: The compile error message should be enough to tell you how to solve your problem.

Comment: @the_lotus: Sorry for the snipped code. I've removed those lines while snipping the code. Could you please check once again?

The _**document**_ object of _**Document()**_ class is being used in _**SaveDoc()**_. Hence I need to pass something which I'm unable to conclude :(

Comment: @Jimi: Sorry for the snipped code. I've removed those lines while snipping the code. Could you please check once again?

Comment: `Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click` doesn't have `document` in its scope so how can you call a method which requires `document`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can declare `document` at the class level. Now all your class' instance members will have access to it, including the event handler.

```
Public Class SC

    Private document As New Document()

    Public Sub SC_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
        Try
            document = New Document() ' it's unclear whether you need this line here or not
            Dim section As Section = document.AddSection()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub SaveDoc(document As Document)
        Dim fname = InputBox("Enter file name:", "file name")
        document.SaveToFile(fname & ".docx", FileFormat.Docx)
        MsgBox("""" & fname & ".DOCX"" is saved!")
    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click
        SaveDoc(document)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: @djv: Thanks a lot for your advise. This worked for me. Also this means I need to clear more basics :p

Comment: @djv Never mind, I got confused by the re-use of the name, I thought the `document` in the context of `SaveDoc` was the class field, I missed that it was the argument instead.

Comment: It would certainly be easier to read if one of the variable names were changed. While we're at it, let's not name the variable the lower-case version of the class! :)